# Infinitely scrolling paging scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, scroll-paging

My UIScrollView has 3 pages, with a separate UIView on each page. This is set up using auto layout. When the app launches, there is one view offscreen to the left, another that is onscreen, and a third offscreen to the right.

When the user pages to either side, there will be one view onscreen, with two views offscreen *on the same side*. What I want to be able to do is move the view furthest offscreen to the other side of the scrollview, to make it so that the scroll view can page infinitely.

I tried changing the constraints in `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate)`, but this approach is not working.

Is this effect plausible? If so, how can I achieve this effect?

**Edit:** One reason the approach before doesn't work is because the user can scroll past the paging without this delegate method being called. I am currently trying to see if the `didScroll` method will allow for the effect I am going for, but I haven't gotten this to the point where I can test it yet.

Comment: *"I tried changing the constraints but this approach is not working."* — please actually *show your attempt* so we can help you figure out why it's not working

Comment: @AaronBrager Sorry, I added some more clarification of why that approach wasn't working. I didn't think it was necessary to include code that doesn't seem like like it can work.

Comment: To do this you have to add *five* of the items, and move around the furthest one as the user pages.

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll is always called so you should be able to move the scrollview there.